# Import System Environment Variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, reactjs

I come from python background, and can use `os. environ['PATH']` to import an system environment variable. I don't see an similar feature in JavaScript. Is there anyway to import it and save it to a variable?

I am beginner in JS and started to learn. I am not using NodeJS but rather simple plain JS script inside HTML tags.

Comment: Javascript runs in the browser. The browser is a separate environment. Think of it as you would run on a different Computer with different os only running with html, css and javascript. You cannot access the computer's data your browser is running on.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

A programming language (usually) can not interact with the operating system on its own, it (usually) needs to import some extra library.

**Python** can not read the environment, but the module `os` can, so you can import `os` in Python and read the environment with `os.environ['PATH']`.

Similarily **Javascript** can not read the environment, but e.g. [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) can, or [deno](https://deno.land/), or [wscript](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wscript) or [cscript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cscript) or [mshta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms536495%28v=vs.85%29), or potentially any application that uses Javascript as a scripting language.

The **browser** (which supports Javascript as a scripting language) **can not read the environment or filesystem on purpose**, for security reasons.

#### conclusion

So you can not get system access from the browser. You need some other coding environment like node or deno or wscript, cscript, HTA, ...

*(I don't have a Windows machine anymore and don't know if the following still works, I think I last tried in Win8)*

If you are on Windows you could use HTA files, which can be written almost like normal HTML pages and support system access e.g. through `ActiveXObject` or other APIs, like:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject");
```

```
var wssh = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
```

HTA files are executed by mshta.exe, which I believe is/was basically an InternetExplorer 6 or something like that (so don't expect the latest JS/HTML features to work).

wscript.exe and cscript.exe can execute Javascript, but without HTML.